# Rails 3.1 with Passenger wrong path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I´m trying to setup a production Server for rails 3.1 with Apache and Phusion Passenger.

It was easy to get my app up and running, but then I noticed, that if I click a Link or try to acces ActiveAdmin in /admin, I´m always redirected with the absolute Server Path. So instead of app.domain.com/admin the url turns to app.domain.com/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/app/public/admin

And then...

```
Routing Error    
No route matches [GET] "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/live/public/admin/login"
```

Now I can remove the wrong Path Segment "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/live/public/" and add a "/" at the end, then the Page shows up.

The subdomain is pointing to the public folder, I already tried other ways to deploy without subdomain etc. but I always end up with this Problem.

The same app is running on Heroku, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution? It's driving me crazy I can get it working everywhere but one particular server.

Answer (score 0):

Place a config.ru into your app root:

```
# Require your environment file to bootstrap Rails
require ::File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/config/environment'

# Serve static assets from RAILS_ROOT/public directory
# use Rails::Rack::Static
# Dispatch the request
run ActionController::Dispatcher.new
```

https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/03/04/phusion-passenger-5-0-1-released/